# how to prevent a thread to freeze the main app in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, freeze

I'm working on a Delphi project. I'v created a class which helps me to connect to web inside a thread;

**I have an issue. this thread freezes main app until the whole response is come.**

so i need your help to overcome this challenge.

Web.pas

```
unit Web;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, IdBaseComponent, Dialogs,
  IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient,
  IdHTTP,
  idMultipartFormData;

type
  TCallBack = reference to procedure(res: String);

type
  TWebThread = class(TThread)
  private
    iniRes, iniURL: String;
    iniParams: TStringList;
    iniCallBack: TCallBack;
    Error : String;
    // var iniCallBack: reference to procedure(arg1:string);
  public
    constructor Create(url:String; Params:TStringList; CallBack:TCallBack);
    // destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute(); override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TWebThread.Create(url:String; Params:TStringList; CallBack:TCallBack);
begin

  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  inherited Create(false);

  Self.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Self.iniURL := url;
  Self.iniCallBack := CallBack;
  Self.iniParams := TStringList.Create;
  iniParams.Assign(Params);

end;


procedure TWebThread.Execute();
var
  lParam: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  IHTTP: TIDHTTP;
  i:Integer;
begin

  // inherited;
  IHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(nil);
  lParam := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  IHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36';

  for i := 0 to iniParams.Count-1 do
  begin
    lParam.AddFormField(iniParams.Names[i], iniParams.ValueFromIndex[i]);
  end;




  try
    try
      iniRes := IHTTP.Post(iniURL, lParam);

      Synchronize(PROCEDURE
                  BEGIN
                    iniCallBack(iniRes);
                  END);


    Except
      on E: Exception do
        Error := E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(IHTTP);
    FreeAndNil(iniParams);
  end;

end;

end.
```

And here is how to use:

```
procedure TMainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Params: TStringList;
  Web: TWebThread;

begin
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  Params.AddPair('Name','Ahmad');
  Params.AddPair('Family','Khaliq');
  Web := TWebThread.Create('http://localhost/get.php', Params,procedure (res : string)
        begin
           Label1.Caption := res;
        end);
  Web.Execute;
end;
```

This is my problem:
This thread, freezes main app until it receives the whole idHTTP response

Comment: As HeartWare points out, never make an explicit call to the `Execute` method. It is called automatically when the create ctor is called with `CreateSuspended` set to false or when `Start` is called after the call to create when `CreateSuspended` is set to true. Note that when `FreeOnTerminate` is set to true, there is no point in keeping a reference to the thread, since any access to the reference may cause an access to an invalid pointer if the thread is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (but haven't verified) that the cause is your explicit call to Web.Execute from your main thread.

The Execute method of a thread should be (and will automatically be) called from within the thread itself - it's not meant to be called from the main thread.

So try to remove the Web.Execute call and see if that doesn't solve the issue you're having.

Synchronize code extract:

```
 if (CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID) and not (QueueEvent and ForceQueue) then
  begin
    if Assigned(ASyncRec.FMethod) then
      ASyncRec.FMethod()
    else if Assigned(ASyncRec.FProcedure) then
      ASyncRec.FProcedure();
  end else
```

Comment: without Web.Execute, nothing happens. It doesn't work at all

Comment: And you're sure that your program calls _inherited Create(false)_ and not "true" ? If so, the thread should auto-call Execute. Try putting a breakpoint at the first line of your Execute method and see if it ever arrives there (it should). If so, sigle-step through the code to see where it goes wrong. The most likely cause is that the HTTP request raises an exception, because you simply swallow it, assigning it to a Class Variable _Error_ that is then simply deallocated when the Execute method terminates.

Comment: Thankyou! now it woks!

Comment: Calling Execute from the main thread would cause the method to run in the main thread instead of a secondary thread, that wouldn't directly cause a freeze. The Synchronize call in the execute is a different matter, you can't call Synchronize from the main thread, that would be the most probable cause.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Synchronize _can_ be called from the main thread (at least in Delphi Rio). In that case, the event/method is just called directly instead of being put in a queue to be called in the main thread. See code extract in answer.

Comment: Thanks. They should update the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) then.